# I can't add an image as shape for python turtle

Tags: python, image, macos, turtle-graphics, shapes

I wrote this little "program" (if we can call him so) and i was trying to add an image (in .gif format) and the IDLE return me those problem

Here the code

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.addshape("turtle_hd.gif")
ninja = turtle.Turtle()
ninja.shape("turtle_hd.gif")
```

The problem that IDLE return me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/matteo/nuovo_costume.py", line 4, in <module>
    screen.addshape("turtle_hd.gif")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 
1133, in register_shape
    shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 
479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 
4061, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 
4006, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "turtle_hd.gif"
```

I'm new of coding world (i have very few notions of this great world) and i'm looking for a hand from someone who is more capable than me

(if it should serve, i'm coding on macOS)

Comment: The first question I'd ask based on your error message is, "Is turtle_hd.gif actually a GIF file or some other image format with a *.gif extension?"  In macOS, in a Terminal window, you can use the `file` command to check the file type:  `file turtle_hd.gif`  it should return something like: `turtle_hd.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 24 x 24`

Comment: i've searched it into my mac and the output is that it is a GIF image. It's just a little bit bigger... 1920 x 1360